# How to develop a maximum and minimum heigh in a vertical layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, height, max

I would like to develop this design:
 [image: The upper layout has a maximum height, and if it overcomes this height: a scroll bar is shown. And the bottom layout has a minimum height, and it is aligned to the bottom of the upper layout]

The upper layout has a maximum height, and if it overcomes this height: a scroll bar is shown. And the bottom layout has a minimum height, and it is aligned to the bottom of the upper layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" >
                <TextView android:id="@+id/quest_question_text"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_quest"
                    style="@style/entry_style"/>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>   

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/answer_list"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time!

May be there is a way to set the weight of the relative layouts depending on how big is the upper layout.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but if you need 50% to be your max just use linear layout and set the weightsum at 2 and make the first child a scrollview with 0dp height and layoutweight 1 let me know if you want the xml

Comment: @Xjasz what I would like to do is what I have drawn,  the code has probably many errors

Comment: I see what you want I'm not sure how to go about setting a min width on a view using layout_weight I'll test something and get back with you

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because solutions should be in their own answer. Please find it [in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c579714a-6aef-4410-99f3-7e1d4730427f/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of would be to use this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quest_question_text"
        style="@style/entry_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_quest"
        android:padding="5sp" />
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/answer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And when the view is created get the height of the device and set your scrollview minheight.

```
scrollView.setMinimumHeight(Height / 2);  <--- for 50%
```